# Predis error when using pipeline with redis-cluster

Tags: redis, cluster-computing, pipeline, predis

i try to add a key-value-pair in my redis-cluster and set expire for the new key in one pipeline. Every time i get an error that the key is moved, but i think that Predis should follow the MOVED-statement like without pipelining.

Isn't it possible to make an expire-call in the pipe? I'm using Predis 1.0.2-dev
with redis_version: 3.0.2

**This works:**

```
$parameters = ['tcp://10.9.200.51:47801', 'tcp://10.9.200.52:47801', 'tcp://10.9.200.53:47801', 'tcp://10.9.200.54:47801'];
$options    = ['cluster' => 'redis'];

$redis = new Predis\Client($parameters, $options);

for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
{
    $rand = mt_rand(1111111,9999999);
    $k = 'test_'.$rand;
    try{
        $redis->set($k, 1);
        $redis->expire($k, 10);
    }
    catch(Exception $ex)
    {
        print_r($ex);
    }
}

?>
```

**This does not work:**

```
$parameters = ['tcp://10.9.200.51:47801', 'tcp://10.9.200.52:47801', 'tcp://10.9.200.53:47801', 'tcp://10.9.200.54:47801'];
$options    = ['cluster' => 'redis'];

$redis = new Predis\Client($parameters, $options);

$pipe = $redis->pipeline();

for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
{
    $rand = mt_rand(1111111,9999999);
    $k = 'test_'.$rand;
    try{
        $pipe->set($k, 1);
        $pipe->expire($k, 10);
    }
    catch(Exception $ex)
    {
        print_r($ex);
    }
}

$pipe->execute();
?>
```

**I get this error:**

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Predis\Response\ServerException' with message 'MOVED 7276 10.9.200.61:47902' in /var/www/predis_test/Predis/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:105
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/predis_test/Predis/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Predis\Pipeline\Pipeline->exception(Object(Predis\Connection\Aggregate\RedisCluster), Object(Predis\Response\Error))
#1 /var/www/predis_test/Predis/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(168): Predis\Pipeline\Pipeline->executePipeline(Object(Predis\Connection\Aggregate\RedisCluster), Object(SplQueue))
#2 /var/www/predis_test/Predis/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(217): Predis\Pipeline\Pipeline->flushPipeline()
#3 /var/www/predis_test/lasttest.php(31): Predis\Pipeline\Pipeline->execute()
#4 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/predis_test/Predis/Pipeline/Pipeline.php on line 105
```

**EDIT:** Seems that pipelining doens't work on redis-cluster. I get the same error when I remove the expire call and have only the set call in a pipe.

Comment: and what is line 105? This sample only has like 23 lines

Comment: Line 105 in /var/www/predis_test/Predis/Pipeline/Pipeline.php. It's an predis class you can find here: https://github.com/nrk/predis/blob/v1.0/src/Pipeline/Pipeline.php

Answer (score 0):

Predis pipeline requires the keys in the same SLOT in cluster(for cluster support auto sharding), which makes it hard for client to handle received moved message from redis cluster server.

More details please refer to the following issue and discussion:

- [Issue: Pipelining with redis-cluster throws exception #267](https://github.com/nrk/predis/issues/267)
- [Discussion: Redis Cluster with Pipeline](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/redis-db/4I0ELYnf3bk/Lrctk0ULm6AJ)

The Conclusion is: do not use pipeline under redis cluster.